# Chart.js Default value when displaying no chart data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm using chart.Js to display my chart. I'm getting my chart data via ajax and graphically render it to display the data,

My question is, there are few cases when my Ajax returns nothing, and my Chart just display X axis and Y axis, with no data or no legend shown. Is there any option to show default text ?

PS: I know I can add some conditional statement and display "No chart Div" and hide my "chart div", but i was some clean method to do the same.

Comment: There are no clean methods. And conditional if with show/hide switch is a good and appropriate solution.

Comment: I think, there is no other solution to do this as you said.!! Thanks mate for your answer !!

Answer (score 8):

You can try this solution:

```
if(1 < chartData.labels.length) {
    chart = new Chart(options.ctx).Line(chartData, options.chartOptions);
} else {
    options.ctx.font = "20px " + Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontFamily;
    options.ctx.textAlign = "center";
    options.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    options.ctx.fillStyle = Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontColor;
    options.ctx.fillText("No data in chart.", options.ctx.canvas.clientWidth / 2, options.ctx.canvas.clientHeight / 2);
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me @imRcH. Can you provide me any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me I hope it helps

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
afterDraw: function (chart) {
                if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length === 0) {
                    // No data is present
                    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                    var width = chart.chart.width;
                    var height = chart.chart.height
                    chart.clear();

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    ctx.font = "20px normal 'Helvetica Nueue'";
                    ctx.fillText('No data to display', width / 2, height / 2);
                    ctx.restore();
                }

            }
});
```