# Show "No data" in angular-chartjs line graph

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have created one line chart using angular-chartjs. In that when I don't have any data its showing blank graph. I need to show one message "No data to show". Let me know how to do this.

Code:
**js code**

```
$scope.linesOption = {
        chart: {
            type: 'lineChart',
            height: 250,
            margin: {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 55
            },
            reduceXTicks: false,
            x: function (d) {
                return d.date;
                //return d3.time.format()(d.date);
            },
            y: function (d) {
                return d.value;
            },
            duration: 100,
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Date',
                ticks: d3.time.days,
                tickFormat: function (d) {
                    return d3.time.format("%A")(new Date(d));
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'deliveries',
                axisLabelDistance: -10
            },
            showLegend: false
        },
        title: {
            enable: true,
            text: 'No of Delivery',
            css: {
                'text-align': 'left',
                'font-size': '14px',
                'margin-left': '20px'
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.linesData = [];
    $scope.linesLabels = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri" , "Sat", "Sun"];
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="panel panel-ocean" style="margin: 2% 1.5%;">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><b>Delivery</b></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <canvas id="delivery-chart" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="linesData" chart-labels="linesLabels"
                                    chart-options="lineOptions"
                                    chart-colors="['#BD762A']" width="480" height="250"
                                    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride">
                            </canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

I need a message in the middle of the blank space saying "No data to show."

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: add a div next to the `<canvas></canvas>` like  `<div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 240px;">No data to show</div>`.  Adjust the positions.  [I create a plunk to show how it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/riuA59X8c1rB92vSjToc?p=preview)

Comment: Dont we have any proper way to do this? like adding some config in option to show message when no data is there.

Comment: it being a canvas html, you can only do it programmatically.  [Check this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403291/chart-js-default-value-when-displaying-no-chart-data), the answer seems to be doing it, not for Angular though.  It sort of looks hackish though.

Comment: Was trying to implement this but didnt able to figure out how to put fillText in linesOptions..

Comment: **[Check this updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKWBBHTG91szBqbucsvL?p=preview)**, this does what you want.  I used jquery to get the canvas context, and you can do what you want to do with it.  If you want to use angular.element instead of jquery, you can do that too.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. Looks like it will work. Really appreciate your help.
--Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Here's the plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vWZwfehDNhv6Q3YBZL7m?p=preview

You can set the text 'no data available' by changing the css top & right.

```
 <canvas id="line" ng-show="isDataAvaiable" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="plot.data" chart-labels="plot.labels" chart-legend="true" chart-colors="plot.color" chart-series="plot.series" chart-options="plot.options" chart-click="plot.callback()" height="250"></canvas>
<b class="no-data-available" ng-hide="isDataAvaiable">No Data Available</b>
```

Here's the css :

```
.no-data-available {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49%;
  right: 45%;
}
```